# Atividades no perfil

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização, perfil

Activities em Inglês. Mencionado aqui recentemente https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286931/the-tabs-on-the-user-profile-pages-are-showing-up-in-portuguese#comment159708_286931

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pelo menos melhorou, [antes todas as abas do perfil estavam em inglês](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2486/).

Comment: Conserto vai pro ar no próximo build!